# Laravel logoutOtherDevices with Fortify

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I built a Laravel app with Fortify authentication. There was a requirement that when the users log in, they should be logged out from all other devices. In the Laravel documentation, it is mentioned that I can use the `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);` method. But it is not clear how to use this with Fortify.

I tried to use this inside the `Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {})` function, but it doesn't work as it checks for a `User` instance inside the `logoutOtherDevices()` method in the  `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class.

By digging a little more in the `Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController` class, I found out that I can pass in a custom login pipeline array in the `app/config/fortify.php` and add my own handler to call the `logoutOtherDevices()` method from there.

I managed to get it working in this way. But I feel something is off with this approach, and I want to see if there's an obvious way to do this (Am I missing something here ?)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you, please, provide solution how have you managed to get it working? TY

Comment: @AlexanderPop I have added it as an answer since this is the only way as of now. Please have a look. hope it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding my current solution with the hope that it will help someone.

If you look at the fortify authentication related classes, you will see that the authentication flows through a pipeline of several handler classes. Although it is not documented, you can customize this flow and add an extra handler by overriding the following in the `config/fortify.php` config file.

```
'pipelines' => [
        'login' => [
            Laravel\Fortify\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
            Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
            App\Actions\Fortify\LogoutOtherDevices::class
        ]
    ]
```

If this block doesn't exist in the config file, you need to add this. The first two are required to get the default authentication process working. The last one: `App\Actions\Fortify\LogoutOtherDevices::class` is my custom handler and that's where you'd add the code to logout the user from other devices.

Create the `App\Actions\Fortify\LogoutOtherDevices` class as shown below and it will work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LogoutOtherDevices
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        // logout other devices
        Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This works fine. But this is not documented anywhere, so there's a chance that they would change this behavior anytime. That's the reason I asked this question to see if there's any other way to do this.

Comment: see my answer above

Comment: I get the error: "The given password does not match the current password" ... even if the password is ok

Comment: Thanks man! This works great. I'm using Jetstream with Inertia

Comment: Its working, but when I add your solution, Laravel fortify 2FA authenticator screen is not working, although the logoutallother devices work. Have you come across this issue?

Answer (score 1):

looks like using pipeline you need follow their doc. take alook https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-the-authentication-pipeline

> To define your custom pipeline, you may use the
> Fortify::authenticateThrough method. This method accepts a closure
> which should return the array of classes to pipe the login request
> through. Typically, this method should be called from the boot method
> of your App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider class.